# No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type when inserting data to a table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, exception, combobox

I have a comboBox in which data are loaded from a table containing Id as primary key and a unique name and data loaded inside comboBox in Load event , now when I'm trying to insert the data into a table it gives me the exception as declared in the question and the exception appearing in the line:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried the solution provided in this link but it gives me the same exception
[ERROR : No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929481/error-no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-data-datarowview-to-a-known-ma)

This is my Load event codes:

```
try
{
   if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
       cn.Open();
   }
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id,name from carsCostsFor", cn);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);
   carCostsCmbo.DataSource = dt;
   carCostsCmbo.ValueMember = "Id";
   carCostsCmbo.DisplayMember = "name";
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

And this is the save button codes:

```
 try
 {
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cn.Open();
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into carsCosts (Id,costId,costFor,costDate,costAmount,costNotes) values (@id,@cId,@for,@date,@amount,@notes)", cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cId", carCostsCmbo.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@for", carCostsCmbo.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", carCostsDateDtp.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", carCostsAmountTxt.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", carCostsNotesRichTxt.Text.Trim());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("تم حفظ البيانات بنجاح");
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Debug your code.  What is the type of carCostsCmbo.SelectedValue?

Comment: What is data type of your db columns..I think problem with that

Comment: @Will the type of carCostsCmbo.SelectedValue is int as the type in the table

Comment: What about other type ?

Comment: What's the type of carCostsCmbo.SelectedItem?  And I don't mean "say what you *think* it is", I mean pretend you have absolutely no idea, go debug your code, and inspect the value.

Comment: Suggest you to create SQL parameters with proper data type and add